# List<Product>.Join(List<Order>, ...) is identical to List<Order>.Join(List<Product>, ...)?

Tags: c#, linq

Up to now, when doing join operation in LINQ, I have no idea how to decide which list must come first and which list must come after. Assume I have two list, `List<Product>` and `List<Order>`.

Edit:

My confusion is to decide

```
List<Product>.Join(List<Order>, ...)
```

or

```
List<Order>.Join(List<Product>, ...)
```

?

Comment: If your query is correct, you won't need to 'decide', that's what the underlying Linq Expressions do. Can you show us an example where you can't 'decide'?

Comment: List<Product>.Join(List<Order>, ...) or List<Order>.Join(List<Product>, ...) <=== this is my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) performs an **inner**, equijoin. From MSDN:

> 'Inner' means that only elements that
>   have a match in the other sequence are
>   included in the results. An 'equijoin'
>   is a join in which the keys are
>   compared for equality.

Consequently, the choice of which sequence is deemed to be the 'outer' one has no impact on the items that will be *present* in the result of the query. All `(outer, inner)` pairs for which their respective projections are equal will make their way in.

However, there will be an impact in terms of the *sequencing* of items in the result. From MSDN:

> Join preserves the order of the
>   elements of outer, and for each of
>   these elements, the order of the
>   matching elements of inner.

Another trivial point is that switching 'outer' and 'inner' will mean the order of the delegate arguments will have to be swapped as well.